# Excel. How to find the same maximum value when we compare two columns with the same index?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following question. Thank you for your help

Excel two columns, one is for index number, other one is for the values. 
As it is seen in the figure, index numbers might correspond different values. 
I want to compare all index numbers 
The values should be same but maximum
If there is no same value leave it blank.

For example, when we compare indices of 1 and 2, the values for index 1 is 6,3,11 and 4. the values for index 2 is 4,2 and 45. So the maximum same number is 4.

I just need a single formula for E3 to copy down.

Thank you for helping.

Figure: [image]

Comment: you should click on the 'tick' if the answer is accepted.. otherwise, please share your thoughts.. (so that this post will be useful for others too) ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there won't be any duplicates within the same indice? If not, try the following:

[image]

Formula in `E3`:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(IF(E$2=$D3,"",FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,IF($A$1:$A$20=$D3,$B$1:$B$20,IF($A$1:$A$20=E$2,$B$1:$B$20,"")))&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=.]"))),"")
```

The `XPATH` syntax will only return nodes that have silimar preceding siblings, while `MAX()` is only included to return the max value when multiple duplciates are encountered between two indices if that's possible.

**Note:** It's an array entered formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: JvdV, Can you also look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62311242/8950875

Comment: if an index weight is equal to other index number, set it the maximum index number as a result. For example, for my specific problem, when we compare 2 and 4 the result is seen 23 for but as you can see one of the weights for 2 is equal to 4. So the result should be 4. I wrote something like this but gives an error: =IF(VLOOKUP(F$2;$D$3:F$11;F$2+1;FALSE)=F$2;MAX(F$2;$D3);IFERR..... How can we solve it? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me.

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula Filter:

```
=IF(E$2<>$D3,IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(FILTER($B$1:$B$20,$A$1:$A$20=$D3)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTER($B$1:$B$20,$A$1:$A$20=$D3),FILTER($B$1:$B$20,$A$1:$A$20=E$2),0))))),""),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner can you look at also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62311242/8950875 Thanks

Comment: if an index weight is equal to other index number, set it the maximum index number as a result. For example, for my specific problem, when we compare 2 and 4 the result is seen 23 for but as you can see one of the weights for 2 is equal to 4. So the result should be 4. I wrote something like this but gives an error: =IF(VLOOKUP(F$2;$D$3:F$11;F$2+1;FALSE)=F$2;MAX(F$2;$D3);IFERR..... How can we solve it? Thanks