# How to find directional roots of a tree using Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have the following question. Thank you for helping

There is a tree with directional roots from bottom to top.
How can find all connections (in pairs) by using Excel?

For example, for column E-> for the child 12; 12-9, 12-6, 12-3 and 12-1, for the child 9; 9-6, 9-3 and 9-1, for the child 6; 6-3 and 6-1, for the child 3, 3-1 are the connections.

What am I supposed to write to L2 and M2 to copy down? (it should not have blank or repeating connections)

Thank you for helping.

[image: Figure.]

Comment: Note regarding your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Mind sharing what you had tried and didn't work ?  /(^_^)

Comment: I find it in two separate tables that I do not like much. First I generate all pairs not professionally. Then I find unique pairs.

Comment: You are going to want vba.  Formula without many helper columns will not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Picture : Stage1 : list all possible pairs for each column | Stage2 : combine the pairs & remove duplicate | Stage3 : put result in the desired format (L & M list..)

[[ Stage 1 ]]

Idea : load the original list[A] > generate index# for L & M [B] > load L & M value using index# [C]

Assuming the data is exactly located as per in table1 in Sheet. Do all these in Sheet2..

[ Creating the template ]

- type "choose" in A1

  type "list :" in D1

  type "how many item :" in A7

  type "how many possible pairs :" in A9

put :

```
=IF(LEN(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROW()-1,$B$1-1))=0,"",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,ROW()-1,$B$1-1)) in E1 and drag until E5
```

table E1 is the "load the original list" [A] part.

Then :

```
=COUNT(E1:E5) in D7
=COMBIN(D7,2) in D9
```

Now, start part [B] : "generate index# for L & M"

Then:

- type "generate list" in A11

  type "#" in A13

  type 1 in A13

  type "L" in K13

  type "M" in L13

put in these formulas :

```
=IF(A14<$D$9,A14+1,"") in A15 and drag until A24
```

then :

```
=D7 in C13
=C13-1 in C14

=IF(COUNTIF($C$14:C14,C14)=C14,C14-1,C14) in C15 and drag until C24
```

then :

```
=$C$13-C14 in D14 and drag until D24
=INDEX($E$1:$E$5,D14) in E14 and drag until E24

=IF(E14<>E13,G13+1,G13) in G14 and drag until G24
=COUNTIF($G$14:G14,G14)+G14 in H14 and drag until H24
=INDEX($E$1:$E$5,H14) in I14 and drag until I24
```

End of part [B], "generating the index#".

Lastly..

```
=IF(A14="","",E14) in K14 and drag until K24
=IF(A14="","",I14) in L14 and drag until L24
```

Column I&E is the [C] part, "load L & M value using index#" .
Where column K&L is the 'cleaned' version

Done creating the template.. for better comprehension.. do these..

- type "use "how many item" value to generate "index #"" in C26

  type "sort the output list as per wanted format" in K26

  type "generate index #" in D27

  type "get L value from list using index #" in E28

  type "get item count from value list" in G30

  type "use "item count" value to generate "index #"" in H31

  type "get M value from list using index #" in I32

[ Using the template ]

To use, enter the column number 1 - 10 in cell B1, and the result is in K13 table..

[ Note ]

This is to generate pairs list for 1 column.. you may extend it another column, by doing the same in sheet3. Change the B1 (select column) value in sheet3 to see/manipulate the result/list in K13 table.

Do it till finish & try to understand each part of the formula.., ask if u r stuck /(^_^)

some ref :

https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-combin-function

---

[[ Stage 2 ]]

Idea : generate address for each sheet > use indirect() to load list as a combined list

Steps : Copy the above to sheet3 and choose column 2 (column 1 in Sheet2).. then repeat.. Sheet4 > Column 5.. Sheet6 > Column 5 .. until Sheet10.. Now create Sheet11 and do these..

- type "Sheet[x]" in A1

  type "2" in A2

  type "Column#" in B1

  type "1" in B2

  type "SheetAddrs" in C1

  type "AddrsOfColmnK" in E1

  type "AddrsOfColmnK" in F1

  type "how many pairs listed per column" in H1

  type "from" in J1

  type "1" in J2

  type "to" in K1

Then :

=A2+1 in A3 and drag until A10
=B2+1 in B3 and drag until B10
="Sheet"&A2&"!" in C2 and drag until C10
=C2&"K:K" in E2 and drag until E10
=C2&"L:L" in F2 and drag until F10
=COUNT(INDIRECT(E2,TRUE)) in H2 and drag until H10
=J2+H2-1 in K2 and drag until K10
=K2+1 in J3 and drag until J10

Using the above as input.. now generate the exact address for each pair in each column and load it..

type "CombineColumnPairList" in M1

type "Column#" in P1

type "pair#" in Q1

type "Gnerate-L-Addrs" in S1

type "Gnerate-M-Addrs" in V1

type "FinalLstWithDuplicate" in Y1

type "L" in Z1

type "M" in AA1

```
=IF(N1<SUM(H:H),N1+1,"") in N2 and drag until N60
=IF(N2="","",MATCH(N2,$J$2:$J$11,1)) in P2 and drag until P60
=IF(N2="","",IF(P2<>P1,1,Q1+1)) in Q2 and drag until Q60
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(P2,B:B,0))&"K" in S2 and drag until S60
=13+Q2 in T2 and drag until T60
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(P2,B:B,0))&"L" in V2 and drag until V60
=T2 in W2 and drag until W60
=INDIRECT(S2&T2,TRUE) in Z2 and drag until Z60
=INDIRECT(V2&W2) in AA2 and drag until AA60
```

Done with the full listing.. in column Z&AA

---

[[ Stage 3 ]]

Idea : from stage2 full list.. > use countif(), if 1, then the pair is unique > Use the "1" to generate another list, the unique pairs only.

- type "[Stage 3] Find Unique" in AC1

  type "howmany unique?" in AG1

  type "FinalLstWithNoDuplicate" in AI1

  type "L" in AK1

  type "M" in AL1

Then :

```
=Z2&"-"&AA2 in AD2 and drag until AD30
=COUNTIF($AD$2:AD2,AD2) in AE2 and drag until AE30
=IF(AE2=1,AF1+1,AF1) in AF2 and drag until AF30
=COUNTIF(AE:AE,1) in AG2
=IF(AJ1<$AG$2,AJ1+1,"") in AJ2 and drag until AJ30
=IFERROR(INDEX(Z:Z,MATCH(AJ2,AF:AF,0)),"") in AK2 and drag until AK30
=IFERROR(INDEX(AA:AA,MATCH(AJ2,AF:AF,0)),"") in AL2 and drag until AL30
```

Column AK&AL should be ur desired resutls.. ( :

Note : Since you had get the logic of the formula/method.. then u know by now that depending on the input table size.. all the given formula are adjustable..

hope it helps.

Comment: I do not need the branch ends. The second formula did not work because for example, for the second column 1, 3 and 4: I need 1-3, 1-4 and 3-4. I also want to write child and parent nodes to the L and M columns to copy down. Thanks

Comment: so.. skip it.. just take `A10:J13` | you said.. "For example, for the 12, 12 9, 12 6, 12 3 and 12 1 are unique connections." It seems like you need the unique brach for Each branch end.. (not overall)

Comment: I do not need the branch ends. The second formula did not work because for example, for the second column 1, 3 and 4: I need 1-3, 1-4 and 3-4. I also want to write child and parent nodes to the L and M columns to copy down. Thanks

Comment: achieve it 1 by 1.... |  column 1 refers to cell A1:A2... | If you are referring to 1,3,4.. we should call it column B. | my question is.. for column C .. the list should be only 1-5 & 3-5 right? Or is should be 1-3, 1-5 and 3-5 ?

Comment: It should be 1-3, 1-5 and 3-5

Comment: Yes. I just need a list of unique connections like 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 3-4, 1-6,1-8,.....  childs should be at column L, parents should be at column M, if possible. We can also take the traspose of the input values.

Comment: Any improvement so far? Thank you for helping

Comment: I'll just help you for the "generate all pairs professionally." part

Comment: There is 3 stage to this.. Stage1 : list all possible pairs for each column | Stage2 : combine the pairs & remove duplicate | Stage3 : put result in the desired format (L & M list..)

Comment: Thanks. Can you share the excel file that you have done? (or a clear picture) It is hard to follow what is going on.

Comment: which part did u stuck at?

Comment: *type 1 in A14. Thank you for your efforts.  I did it. Do you think this is the best solution? Is there any way to process 1st 3rd 5th 7th 9th column at the same time? It looks it is not professional to copy and paste several times.

Comment: "this is the best solution?" Afaik, this is my best.. (as mentioned) for Stage1  || " process 1st 3rd 5th 7th 9th column at the same time?" That is Stage2 || Thanks God you had learnt the processes for stage1. Actually.. we had just created http://www.ne.jp/asahi/math.edu/ami/myprog/jk_eng.htm manually..  [ I'm not good in vba so I cannot teach u to create something like that.. ] (personally I'm happy u r catching up to this stage) /(^_^)

Comment: Now for Stage2 (list each column possible pairs).. Copy the A1:L23 in Sheet2 to Sheet3, then Sheet4 until Sheet11.. || Once done create Sheet12 and combine the list. I had added the steps.. Just comment If u didn't get the logic behind.. || Bonus : Stage3 is done too.. | if it work.. please click on the 'tick'

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed all your steps. It works but it is not handy. It is very exhausting. I think, there might be another solution. I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: "It is very exhausting" for the 1st time.. yup.. I agree.. imho, (since I known the algorithm byheart) it's not that complicated actually.. | Since u had understand the algorithm (the stage1/2/3 thing..) , now you may excute it in 'any' data manipulation tools/code/software later.. [ My aim here is always to instill algorithm over method ] | In this case.. since the method is know.. there is no problem handling 'any' new data size u'have later.. u may also execute it with python, vba, matlab, mathematica or even javascrpt This (the same output) may just be a 40 lines of code away..

Comment: I'm really glad that you had learnt the process.. But I'm sorry.. in excel, there is no direct to do Stage1/2/3.. but in mathematica.. there is.. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808788/generating-combinations) [Ref2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html).. U'r request is not complicated.. just that excel don't have such function. We had just manually created one.. (I hope this is still an achievement of some sort..)

Comment: Note : to use mathematica without installing.. you may go to this [online lab](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/)