# Excel - How can I list all items in a range to a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How can I pull all the items in a range to list those in a single column?
Repeating items can take place only ones. 
There might be numbers and texts in the cells

Thanks
Best

[image: Figure]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns/62205206#62205206

Comment: @ScottCraner - was literally going to add a plug to the same answer :-)

Comment: @BigBen how can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62311242/8950875

Comment: You should probably use VBA, as mentioned already in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311242/how-to-find-directional-roots-of-a-tree-using-excel#comment110263720_62311242).

Comment: @BigBen I added the VBA as a keyword to the question. Am I doing correct or do I need to ask this question again? Thanks

Comment: You would need to include the VBA you already tried.... SO is not meant to be a code-writing service.